# Count just Non-empty cells in an Excell worksheet using IronXl

Tags: c#, ironxl

I am using IronXl nuget package to count the occupied cell in each column of an Excel worksheet. I am using the following code, but it returns also the empty cells which had been filled one time and are cleared now; They are counted unless I delete the entire row by clicking on the excel file and then click that row. How is it possible to count just Non-empty cells in an Excell worksheet using IronXl, without deleting the cleared cell in the excel file?

```
int maxIndex = otherWorksheet.Columns[1].Count;
```

Comment: I asked the IronXl support team. They said I should check the cells one by one,

Answer (score 1):

I have tried assigning the cell's value to both empty and null, as well as retrieving the FilledCells property of the worksheet. These does not seem to work.

**Solution:** You can use LINQ to select only the cells that have content in them.

```
WorkBook workBook = WorkBook.Create();
WorkSheet workSheet = workBook.DefaultWorkSheet;

workSheet["A1:A10"].Value = "Hello";
workSheet["A5:A10"].ClearContents();

foreach(var row in workSheet.Rows)
{
    foreach(var col in row)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(col.Value);
    }
}

var cells = workSheet.Rows.Where(cell => cell.Value.ToString() != "")
    .Select(cell => cell);
        
foreach(var cell in cells)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cell.Value);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't find my code for it but I did something like the following.

```
static int CountNonEmptyCells(WorkSheet otherWorkSheet, int colnum)
  {
      var row = otherWorkSheet.Columns[colnum];
      int count = 0;
          // Iterate through each cell in the row
          foreach (var cell in row.Cells)
          {
              // Check if the cell is not empty
              if (cell.Text != "")
              {
                  count++;
              }
          }
      return count;
  }
```

Note: This will count all non-empty cells in the column and only non-empty cells.
If you want something that will count all cells, empty or not, up to the last populated cell in the row:

```
static int CountNonEmptyCells(WorkSheet otherWorkSheet, int colnum)
        {
            var row = otherWorkSheet.Columns[colnum];
            string lastCellAddress;

            int count = 0;
                // Iterate through each cell in the row
                foreach (var cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    // Check if the cell is not empty
                    if (cell.Text != "")
                    {
                        lastCellAddress = cell.AddressString;
                    }
                }
            //build a string to represent the range of values in the column
            //the regex is getting all non-numerical charaters in the string before the first numerical charaters
            string rangeStr = 
                Regex.Match(lastCellAddress, @"^([^0-9]+)").Groups[1].Value  
                + "1:" + lastCellAddress;
          
            var range = otherWorkSheet[rangeStr];
          
            //you can probably just return range.Count in place of this
            foreach (var cell in range)
            {
                count++;
            }
            return count;
        }
```